# Is there an inexpensive way to transfer colour data from a RenderTarget2D on a per frame basis?

Tags: c#, windows, xna, xna-4.0

Until recently, our game checked collisions by getting the colour data from a section of the background texture of the scene. This worked very well, but as the design changed, we needed to check against multiple textures and it was decided to render these all to a single RenderTarget2D and check collisions on that.

```
public bool TouchingBlackPixel(GameObject p)
    {
        /*
        Calculate rectangle under the player...
        SourceX,SourceY: Position of top left corner of rectangle
        SizeX,SizeY: Aproximated (cast to int from float) size of box
        */

        Rectangle sourceRectangle = new Rectangle(sourceX, sourceY,
                                                   (int)sizeX, (int)sizeY);

        Color[] retrievedColor = new Color[(int)(sizeX * sizeY)];

        p.tileCurrentlyOn.collisionLayer.GetData(0, sourceRectangle, retrievedColor,
                                                     0, retrievedColor.Count());

        /*
        Check collisions
        */
    }
```

The problem that we've been having is that, since moving to the render target, we are experiencing massive reductions in FPS.

From what we've read, it seems as if the issue is that in order to get data from the RenderTarget2D, you need to transfer data from the GPU to the CPU and that this is slow. This is compounded by us needing to run the same function twice (once for each player) and not being able to keep the same data (they may not be on the same tile).

We've tried moving the GetData calls to the tile's Draw function and storing the data in a member array, but this does not seem to have solved the problem (As we are still calling GetData on a tile quite regularly - down from twice every update to once every draw).

Any help which you could give us would be great as the power that this collision system affords us is quite fantastic, but the overhead which render targets have introduced will make it impossible to keep.

Comment: Are you generating the collision layer in a shader? Typically you'd keep a local copy on the CPU and use that or a derived data structure for collision detection, or handle the collision within the shader, as well.

Comment: The collision layer is created by setting the render target on the graphics device and then drawing a sprite batch. I don't think this uses shaders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is: **Don't do that**.

It sounds like offloading the compositing of your collision data to the GPU was a performance optimisation that didn't work - so the correct course of action would be to revert the change.

You should simply do your collision checks all on the CPU. And I would further suggest that it is probably faster to run your collision algorithm multiple times and determine a collision response by combining the results, rather than compositing the whole scene onto a single layer and running collision detection once.

This is particularly the case if you are using the render target to support transformations before doing collision.

(For simple 2D pixel collision detection, see [this sample](http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/tutorial/collision_2d_perpixel). If you need support for transformations, see [this sample](http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/tutorial/collision_2d_perpixel_transformed) as well.)

Comment: Moving it to the GPU wasn't exactly our choice as we wanted to check all the layers at once and render targets exist on the GPU, but I understand what you're getting at. Does this mean that there is no way to use our current system without the adverse framerate? Would it be a good idea to offload the collision detection itself to the GPU to avoid having to shuffle the data around? I've seen the examples before and our system is actually a bit better than them, but falls down when you use render targets (as does theirs) due to the required transfer from GPU to CPU.

Comment: I can't say for certain that there is *no* way to get it in some framerate/hardware budget (particularly as I don't have details). But I can assure you that it's a very, very slow operation. You'd be better off spending programming and hardware resources doing it on the CPU. Offloading the whole thing to the GPU is probably a bad plan if at any point you have to bring data back to the CPU.

Comment: I think you may be right. We'll just have to check collisions on each object separately instead of unifying the system. It's a shame since we had a good system which allowed for some fairly impressive feedback from collisions, but the overhead from accessing the gpu every frame is just too high.

Comment: @LlamaCloud If your system requires compositing a scene, that is still possible on the CPU. It's not the recommended way - because of performance - but if there's some tangible benefit to colliding against the entire scene at once, you should go for it. You'll need to do a lot of optimisation, though. Might want to look up "blitting" for some resources. What you will particularly want to do is ensure you are only processing collision data - no need to recreate the scene in full-colour. Pre-create black-and-white collision masks for each sprite and use those.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into that. The system determined behaviours from the colour data of the colliding pixels, so I'm not too keen on removing the colours, but this might be possible to encode in some other way. It was also suggested by a colleague that drawing to a smaller render target (constrained to the size and location of the player) after drawing the full scene might allow the original system to be preserved as the GPU won't be handling as much data transfer but I've not tried this yet. Do you think this might be a valid suggestion?

Comment: @LlamaCloud Yes, very much so. I was assuming you had tried that and performance was still poor.

Comment: No, it seems this had never occurred to us. We have little knowledge of what a render target actually does (only found out that it was in GPU space a few days ago) and hadn't considered that a smaller target would be simpler as we were always only asking for the rectangle of colour data from around the player. Having just implemented the small render target method, it seems to work at a fairly stable 60fps. I guess we'll chalk that one up to experience. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: It seems I spoke too soon. Whilst it appeared to be colliding correctly, it was only copying a few of the pixels across and these happened to be roughly correct (they were black and I was on black). I've created another question for this problem [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9646521) if you can help at all.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose, your tile's collision layer does not change. Or at least changes not very frequently. So you can store the colors for each tile in an array or other structure. This would decrease the amount of data that is transfered from the GPU to CPU, but requires that the additional data stored in the RAM is not too big.

Comment: This would be fine, however we cannot rule out the possibility that the collision layer will change. We currently have one tile which has a constantly shifting layer and all of them can have changes imparted on them by the player. This ensures the impossibility of using such a method since as soon as the player entered a shifting tile (or changed the tile themselves), we would have to get new data and this would instantly kill the framerate.

Comment: Another option would be to implement a kind of caching system that polls the information from the GPU only if it has been updated and if it is necessary.

Comment: As mentioned in the question text (though, I've noticed, slightly inaccurately and I'll edit to correct), we've tried just grabbing the data when it draws and this did not produce a noticeable improvement. We haven't tried making sure that it only grabs it if changes but we have to be able to use this system even if it changes every frame (as it does in our 'Rain' scene), so this would not solve the problem.